# Where in the Mahanarayana Upanishad is the Nyasa Vidya, the path of surrender to Vishnu?

Tags: vishnu, upanishads, sri-vaishnava, vedanta, mahanarayana-upanishad

As I discuss in the [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/3193/36), by far the most popular school of Hindu philosophy is the Vedanta school, which bases its tenets on the doctrines laid out in the Brahma Sutras, a work by the sage Vyasa which summarizes and systematizes the philosophical teachings of the Upanishads. You can read the Brahma Sutras [here](http://www.advaita.it/library/brahmasutras2.htm). In any case, Adhyaya 3 Pada 3 of the Brahma Sutras describes the Brahma Vidyas, 32 lessons found in the various Upanishads which can each lead you to Brahman if you meditate on them. You can see the full list of 32 Vidyas [here](http://www.advaita.it/library/brahmasutras2.htm).

One of these Vidyas is the Nyasa Vidya of the Mahanarayana Upanishad. It concerns the path of Sharanagati or complete surrender to Vishnu, which is emphasized by Sri Vaishnavas as I discuss [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/7971/36) and [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/6504/36).  But my question is, where in the Mahanarayana Upanishad is the Nyasa Vidya found?

Here is what [this web page](http://ramanuja.org/sri/Web/BrahmaVidya) says:

> 24. Nyaasa Vidya — Self-surrender 
>       Taittiriya Narayanam, 49–52

For those who don't know, the reason the Mahanarayana Upanishad is called the Taittiriya Narayana Upanishad is because it constitutes the 10th section of the Taittiriya Aranyaka of the Yajur Veda, as opposed to the Taittiriya Upanishad which constitutes the 7th, 8th, and 9th sections as I discuss [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/2204/36).  In any case, you can read the Mahanarayana Upanishad [here](http://www.advaita.it/library/mahanarayana.htm).  But what does "49-52" mean?

Does it mean verses 49-52?  Here are verses 49-52 of section 1 of the Mahanarayana Upanishad:

> svasti no maghavā karotu । 
>  hantu pāpmānaṃ yo'smān dveṣṭi ॥
>   49॥
>
> somānam̐ svaraṇaṃ kṛṇuhi brahmaṇaspate kakṣīvantaṃ ya
>   auśijam । 
>   śarīraṃ yajñaśamalaṃ kusīdaṃ tasmintsīdatu yo'smān
>   dveṣṭi ॥ 50॥
>
> caraṇaṃ pavitraṃ vitataṃ purāṇaṃ  yena pūtastarati
>   duṣkṛtāni । 
>   tena pavitreṇa śuddhena pūtā  ati pāpmānamarātiṃ tarema ॥ 51॥
>
> sajoṣā indra sagaṇo marudbhiḥ  somaṃ piba vṛtrahañchūra
>   vidvān । 
>  
>   jahi śatrūm̐rapa mṛdho nudasvāthābhayaṃ kṛṇuhi viśvato
>   naḥ ॥ 52॥
>
> I-49: May Indra grant us welfare. May he destroy the evil one hostile
>   to us.
>
> I-50: O Lord of prayers, make me the presser of soma juice, well
>   known among the gods like Kakshivan, the son of Usik. Make me
>   physically capable of performing sacrifices. Let those who are hostile
>   to us remain ‘there’ long, in the hell.
>
> I-51: He who is rendered holy by the ancient, widespread,
>   sanctifying feet (or by virtuous conduct) crosses over evil deeds and
>   their effects. Having been rendered holy by that naturally pure and
>   purifying feet of the Lord (or conduct) may we overcome our enemies,
>   the sins.
>
> I-52: O Indra, O slayer of Vritra, O valorous one and all-knowing
>   one, accept with pleasure our soma oblation in the company of your
>   retinue and troop of gods. Slay our enemies, give us victory in battle
>   and grant us safety and fearlessness from every quarter.

Or does it mean sections 49-52?  Here they are:

> harim̐ harantamanuyanti devā viśvasyeśānaṃ vṛṣabhaṃ matīnām । 
>   brahmasarūpamanu medamāgādayanaṃ mā vivadhīrvikramasva ॥
>
> śalkairagnimindhāna ubhau lokau sanemaham । 
>  ubhayorlokayorṛdhvāti
>   mṛtyuṃ tarāmyaham ॥
>
> mā chido mṛtyo mā vadhīrmā me balaṃ vivṛho mā pramoṣīḥ । 
>  prajāṃ
>   mā me rīriṣa āyurugra nṛcakṣasaṃ tvā haviṣā vidhema ॥
>
> mā no mahāntamuta mā no arbhakaṃ  mā na ukṣantamuta mā na ukṣitam ।
>   
>  mā no vadhīḥ pitaraṃ mota mātaraṃ  priyā mā nastanuvo rudra
>   rīriṣaḥ ॥
>
> XLIX-1: Like servants gods follow Hari who is the Lord of the
>   universe, who leads all thoughts as the foremost leader and who
>   absorbs into Himself the universe at the time of dissolution (or who
>   destroys the sins of devotees). May this path to liberation taught in
>   the Vedas having the same form as Brahman open itself to me. Deprive
>   not me of that. Strive to secure it for me.
>
> L-1: Kindling the consecrated fire with chips of wood (in order to
>   offer oblations during worship) may I attain both the worlds. Having
>   attained the prosperity of this world and the next I shall cross over
>   death.
>
> LI-1: O fierce Death, do not cut off my life. Do not injure (my
>   interest). Do not cripple my strength. Do not subject me to
>   deprivation. Do not hurt my progeny and life. I shall serve thee with
>   oblations; for, thou art vigilant over the deeds of men.
>
> LII-1: O Rudra, injure not our elders, our children, our adults
>   capable of procreation, the foetus we have laid in the mother’s womb
>   and our father and mother. Do not hurt our dear selves.

So does anyone know for sure what verses constitute the Nyasa Vidya?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The webpage has a typo and is missing a leading '1'. The Nyasa-Vidya is described in the concluding 6 sections of the Taittiriya-Narayana-valli aka Mahanarayana-Upanishad. This would make it sections 149-152, not 49-52. The numbering also is broken. Rangaramanuja's version of the Upanishad has only 150 sections and Nyasavidya is covered in sections 145-150.

For reference, here is the original text and Vishishtadvaitic translation/interpretation according to Upanishad Bhashyakara Rangaramanuja Muni. The excerpt is from the book Upanishads by NS Anantharangachar. I have included the entire section on Nyasa. Though there is liberal use of devanagari within the translation, it is still quite readable even if you don't know the script.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]